# Where can I download the English LEGO Catalog for 2005 to 2014?

Tags: sets

I tried Google and found a LEGO catalog that is mostly in German.

May I know where can I download LEGO Catalog (English version) for the year 2005 to 2014, in PDF format?

Answer (score 4):

Brickset.com maintains an [archive of all catalogues](http://brickset.com/library/catalogues) they can find. Unfortunately it only goes up to 1999 at this time.

Comment: It's 1966 by now.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty extensive [collection of Russian catalogs](http://vselego.ru/catalogs/). It does cover the years you requested. Since the catalogs are mostly images, I imagine that may be sufficient (and the part numbers are there). You can use Google Translate to navigate around the site.

Answer (score 0):

I could mail mine to you, If the catalogue part is what you're looking for.